# QGIS 3.22.10: problems with cursor, while writing a filter

Tags: qgis, cursor, filter

I just remarked a problem in QGIS 3.22, I never had before. When I write a filter for a layer, then the cursor is several millimeters right of the place where I write. This makes it difficult to write more complicated filters. In the first screenshot (1) I just wrote the quotation mark, but the cursor is 5mm further to the right.[image]
Is it possible that it has something to do with the size of the letters I use? In the screenshot 2 you see the general settings. [image]

When I write for example in the attribute table, this problem does not occur. My OS is Ubuntu 22.04. Does anybody know this problem?

Now I just found that the problem does not occur when I start the same project with a new profile. But I have no idea, why the problem occurred with the old profile.

Some hours later, when I start the same project (with new profile), the same problem occurs again.

I made a short video to show the problem more clearly
https://youtu.be/ZVpLet8wrVw
When I delete letters in the filter or when I write new letters, the cursor does not fit to the letters.

Comment: Is the problem reproducible if you override the system localization and configure a profile to use in English? I have a profile in Spanish and there are strange behaviors with the cursor too, but can't reproduce them in English.

Comment: Yes, its the same on my pc. When I change the language to (American) english, I cannot reproduce the problem.  Usually I work with QGIS in german. - And I tried something else: I installed QGIS 3.26.2 on another computer. Language german. And there everything is ok, the problem does not occur. - I think it is a bug in QGIS 3.22.

Comment: Look also here https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/50030

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu 22.04 running QGIS 3.22.11. The cursor is not in the correct location using any expression. Any fix?